# Build.gradle: Access to 'project' exceeds its access rights

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**constants.gradle**

```
project.ext {
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
}
```

**build.gradle** of the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../constants.gradle'

android {

    compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion project.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
    ...
```

[image]

What is wrong here?

Though it works fine for libraries in the same project:

[image]

Also everything is fine for the next lines in `defaultConfig` block

```
minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion project.ext.targetSdkVersion
```

[image]

Android Studio 3.2, `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'`, `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`

Seems it didn't show such warnings with the previous Gradle or Studio

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's just a warning and It should work.

Because when you use `project` inside `android` scope, Gradle tries to find the invocation location of `project`.

[image: List of project candidates reported by IDE]

You have two options to fix this warning.

Get your constants outside of `android` scope.

```
def compileSdkVersion = project.ext.compileSdkVersion
def buildToolsVersion = project.ext.buildToolsVersion

android {

    compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion buildToolsVersion
    ...
```

Or update your `constants.gradle`:

```
ext {
    buildVersions = [
      minSdkVersion : 19,
      compileSdkVersion : 28,
      targetSdkVersion : 28,
      buildToolsVersion : '28.0.3',
      supportLibraryVersion : '28.0.0',
    ]
}
```

and use it in your `build.gradle` like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../constants.gradle'

android {

    compileSdkVersion buildVersions.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion buildVersions.buildToolsVersion
    ...
```

Comment: Your second solutions gives an error. The IDE shows that the syntax is invalid for buildVersions = [ ... ]. If you add commas between items then it doesn't show an error. Also if you wrap with curly braces it also doesn't show as a syntax error. Neither of those actually resolve though.

Comment: If anyone else is looking for this, the correct syntax for Saeed Masoumi's second solution is: ext { buildVersion = [ minSdk: 19, compileSdk: 28, targetSdk: 28 ] } (I cannot comment, otherwise I'd have put that below their answer)

Answer (score 0):

The same variables naming (compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersion) was incorrect in my case, here's an example of working code:

```
def compileSdkVer = 30
def buildToolsVer = '29.0.3'

android {
    compileSdkVersion compileSdkVer
    buildToolsVersion buildToolsVer
defaultConfig {
...
```