# Access to 'viewBinding' exceeds its access rights

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, android-viewbinding

[image]

After updating Android Studio to **Arctic Fox** and Android Gradle plugin to **7.0.0** I'm facing this warning, I mean the app can be built successfully nonetheless of this warning but what I am missing here? What's the problem here?

According to the official View Binding [reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), I'm enabling it the right way.
here is my [build.gradle](https://github.com/yamin8000/Fare/blob/master/app/build.gradle) if anyone is interested in checking.

There are some related questions but I don't think they are relevant in this situation.

- [Build.gradle: Access to 'project' exceeds its access rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676917/build-gradle-access-to-project-exceeds-its-access-rights)
- [Enable viewBinding feature failed (Android Studio 3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040546/enable-viewbinding-feature-failed-android-studio-3-6)

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Remove equal sign. On the screenshot you use Kotlin configuration, but Groovy is needed here. See the difference:

[image: ViewBinding usage]

Comment: For people wondering what's the exact difference its the difference in the syntax used in Kotlin and Groovy

Comment: lol at the amount of upvotes here, IDE could be clearer

Comment: @DanielWilson Better that developers get familiar with Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your file 'build.gradle' to 'build.gradle.kts'.
And change its content to the appropriate Kotlin DSL syntax where necessary.

Comment: Yeah, that's an option too. I have nothing against Kotlin DSL in build.gradle but I think removing an equal sign is way easier and faster than migrating my build.gradle file to Kotlin DSL syntax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).